# Uploading images to different folder in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm creating an application were users get to upload two type of image which is their profile picture and their profile cover picture. But I'm having issues defining the different process without interference from each other as I'm unable to call two `onActivityResult`.

this is the code I'm currently using to upload profile picture to firebase storage

```
  coverbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "SELECT IMAGE"), GALLERY_PICKER);
        }
    });

    mImagebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "SELECT IMAGE"), GALLERY_PICK);

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        mPdialog = new ProgressDialog(SettingsActivity.this);
        mPdialog.setTitle("Uploading");
        mPdialog.setMessage("please wait....");
        mPdialog.show();

        Uri imageUri = data.getData();

        CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                .setMinCropWindowSize(500,500)
                .start(SettingsActivity.this);

    }

    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

            File file_thumb = new File(resultUri.getPath());

            String current_uid = mCurrentuser.getUid();

            Bitmap thumb_bitmap = new Compressor(this)
                    .setMaxWidth(200)
                    .setMaxHeight(200)
                    .setQuality(75)
                    .compressToBitmap(file_thumb);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            thumb_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            final byte[] thumb_byte = baos.toByteArray();

            StorageReference filepath = mImageReference.child("profile_images").child(current_uid + ".jpg");
            final StorageReference thumb_path = mImageReference.child("profile_images").child("thumbs").child(current_uid + ".jpg");
            filepath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()){

                        final String download_url = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                        UploadTask uploadTask = thumb_path.putBytes(thumb_byte);
                        uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> thumb_task) {

                                String thumb_downloadurl = thumb_task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                                if (thumb_task.isSuccessful()){

                                    Map update_hashmap = new HashMap();
                                    update_hashmap.put("image",download_url);
                                    update_hashmap.put("thumb_image", thumb_downloadurl);

                                    mDatabase.updateChildren(update_hashmap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                                mPdialog.dismiss();
                                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                }else {
                                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    mPdialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }
                        });


                        }else {
                        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        mPdialog.dismiss();

                    }
                }
            });

        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            Exception error = result.getError();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is happening when you are using this code? Do you have an error? Where are the images uploaded?

Answer (score 1):

Try this
Move startActivityForResult & intent outside 
Set intent requestCode according to which button was clicked

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
coverbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);


    }
});

mImagebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);


    }
});
```

}
               startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "SELECT IMAGE"), GALLERY_PICKER);